# How to make static_assert block re-usable in template classes?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17, static-assert

Say I have a template class that makes multiple static_asserts:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
    static_assert(!std::is_const<T>::value,"");
    static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>::value,"");
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>::value,"");

    //...<snip>...
}
```

Now say I have more template classes that need to make the same asserts.

Is there a way to make a `static_assert`  block reusable? A "static_assert function" if you will.

Comment: If I understood correctly what you mean by `static_assert` block, looks like you can put those asserts into a template class and inheri `Foo` from from it. Let me know if you'd like code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is build a new trait that is a [`conjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) of the traits you want to check.  Since you want the negation of all of those traits that would literally translate to

```
template<typename T>
using my_trait = std::conjunction<std::negation<std::is_const<T>>,
                                  std::negation<std::is_reference<T>>,
                                  std::negation<std::is_pointer<T>>>;

static_assert(my_trait<int>::value, "");
```

but having to use `std::negation` for every trait is/can be a pain.  You can get rid of that though using [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) to get an "or" of all the traits and then just negate the value in the static assert like you do which gives you

```
template<typename T>
using my_trait = std::disjunction<std::is_const<T>,
                                  std::is_reference<T>,
                                  std::is_pointer<T>>;

static_assert(!my_trait<int>::value, "");
```

Comment: @JeJo That is another valid option.  There are quite a few ways to skin this cat.  I just didn't want to introduce any actual variables.

Comment: @SergeyA Wow.  I messed that up.  Thanks for the spot.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can just combine required traits into one with descriptive name:

```
template<typename T> using
is_fancy = ::std::integral_constant
<
    bool
,   (not std::is_const<T>::value)
    and
    (not std::is_reference<T>::value)
    and
    (not std::is_pointer<T>::value)
>;
```

and use it later:

```
static_assert(std::is_fancy<T>::value,"");
```

Comment: Totally a question of preference, but I would rather inherit from `bool_constant`.

Comment: @SergeyA Good point, though I would typically just declare an alias because inheritance seems to be putting more burden on compiler.

Comment: Interesting observation about compile-time costs of inheritance vs alias. Never checked, how did you measure that?

Comment: @SergeyA instantiating a new type is usually harder than resolving an alias

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot sure, but I wonder if the effect is quantifiable.

Comment: @SergeyA "measure" would probably be a bold term, but for some time I've been fighting with compilation failures caused by compiler (gcc) running out of RAM on some relatively template-heavy code base. And limiting spawning of new template types (especially in recursive manner) proved to be the most efficient way to counter them.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `constexpr bool` which does the evaluation at compile time:

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_okay_type = !std::is_const<T>::value &&
                                     !std::is_reference<T>::value &&
                                     !std::is_pointer<T>::value;
```

Then either:

1. use it **directly `static_assert<>`**, as you did in your example:

   ```
   template<typename T> class MyClass
   {
       static_assert(is_okay_type<T>, "message");
   public:
       //...code...
   };
   ```
2. or you can make **conditional instantiation of the template class**,
   depending on the template argument.

   ```
   template<typename Type, typename Enable = void> class Class1;

   template<typename Type>
   class Class1<Type, std::enable_if_t<is_okay_type<Type>> >
   {
       //...code...
   };
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I've seen a few good answers, using the conjunction.
Unfortunately, these are really hard to debug. I've once had to debug an issue with my class stating: requirements met. This was a too long list to understand. I finally copied all underlying checks one by one.

When possible, I like to keep them split:

```
template<typename T>
struct CustomCheck {
     static_assert(check<T>);
      // ...
 };
```

In your class, you only have to instantiate it to get the checking and a detailed error:

```
 constexpr static CustomCheck<T> check{};
```