# How to pass a not explicitly string literal error message to a static_assert?

Tags: c++, string-literals, static-assert

I have a few static asserts in different places in code.

```
static_assert(bool_constexpr_1, error_message);
...
static_assert(bool_constexpr_2, error_message);
```

And want all of them to share the same `error_message`.

The first solution is to copy-paste the message.

The second one is to `#define` the `error_message`.

Is there something better?

P.S. I expected `static constexpr auto` to work, yet it failed.

Comment: Not possible. It must be a string literal.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7778734/1896169

Comment: I've used `static constexpr auto name[] = ""` before, have you tried that already?

Comment: @JVApen Are you sure.  `static_assert` requires the message to be a string literal.

Comment: No, ain't sure, I know it works in some template situations where everything else ain't working

Comment: @JVApen It doesn't seem to work

Comment: @JesperJuhl The compiler will most likely not even include those strings in the executable. I'd be surprised if they existed even on `-O0`.

Comment: @Justin - Well, it has to include them at least *once* ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl No, it doesn't. The string literal is being used inside a `static_assert` and is never used at runtime

Comment: @Justin - my bad. Right you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either have to copy-paste the literal, or use the preprocessor.  Per [[dcl.dcl]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.dcl#1) The grammar of `static_assert` is defined as

> ```
> static_assert-declaration:
>       static_­assert ( constant-expression ) ;
>       static_­assert ( constant-expression , string-literal ) ;
> ```

So you either provide a string literal, or you don't.  There is no other way to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question sounds a lot like a variation: [How to make static_assert block re-usable in template classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55800316/2466431)

You have defined it a bit to generic, however, as you want to reuse the same 'error' message, I would assume that your check will also be similar. Let's use an example where you want to force inheritance:

```
 struct Interface {};
 struct Impl : Interface {};
 struct Other {};
 static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Interface, Impl>, "Implementations should inherit from the interface. See document at ... for more details."); // Success
 static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Interface, Other>, "Implementations should inherit from the interface. See document at ... for more details."); // Failure
```

Here, it might make sense to implement your own type trait. For example:

```
 template<typename T> using FrameworkInjectionRequirement = std::is_base_of<Interface, T>
 template<typename T> constexpr bool FrameworkInjectionRequirement_v = FrameworkInjectionRequirement<T>::value;

  static_assert(FrameworkInjectionRequirement_v<Impl>);
```

By doing this, you already gave a good name to what you try to check, which could be sufficient in order to use the terse version of static_assert instead, without needing an explanation.

Alternatively, you could wrap you assert into a struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct FrameworkInjectionRequirement {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Interface, T>, "Implementations should inherit from the interface. See document at ... for more details.");
};
constexpr static FrameworkInjectionRequirement<Impl> check{}; // Success
constexpr static FrameworkInjectionRequirement<Other> check{}; // Failure
```

By instantiating this zero-size struct at compile time (thanks to `constexpr` on the variable), the assert will be checked.
Not only can you reuse the message into it, you again gave your check a good name. As a bonus, you can split up the different elements creating the boolean expression into it's distinct elements, which will assist you if one of them fails.